# Did not found root folder browser after upgrading to latest

Tags: filesystem

Today I have upgrade my system with ubuntu 13.04 . But I Did not found the root file system .
Please help me how do I access the files , a lot of files are in /opt folder .

Thanks
Biplab

Comment: "Did not found the root file system", the root filesystem is in `/`. Can you explain what you used to have and don't have anymore? And how did you upgrade your system?

Answer (score 0):

First of all check out what exactly is in '/' folder - do it using Terminal.

```
ls /
```

There really should be 'opt' folder. You can check out what exactly is in it by `ls` command or just use Nautilus.

```
sudo nautilus /opt
```

It's better to use with sudo because normal user cannot do much there.

Hope that will help.